# AWS Lambda Python Package Deployment With Java

Tags: java, python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have written a python code on local ubuntu environment but now i need to deploy it into AWS Lambda. In my code i am using java using shell command.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["java -jar jarfile.jar input_file output_file], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
```

Java is installed on ubuntu using

```
sudo apt install default-jre
sudo apt install default-jdk
```

Unlike python packages, java is installed globally. How will i build python deployment package that contains Java Library so that it can be used using Shell Command ?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably convert the Java code into another Lambda function, or just write a Java Lambda function that does nothing but call that Java code inside the jar file.

Deploy that as a separate Lambda function and invoke it from the Python Lambda function.

Comment: Would there be a considerable delay with this method? Or if I create them in same region, then only minimal delay?

Comment: There are also custom runtimes: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-custom.html